# Histogram Comparison

Tags: java, android, opencv

I need some help with code. I want to write someting similar to: 
[LINK](https://code.google.com/p/javacv/wiki/OpenCV2_Cookbook_Examples_Chapter_4#Example_9_-_compute_image_similarity)

I have two small .png pictures from frontal phone camera. I have a problem with calc histograms. There is code:

```
        Mat img=new Mat();
        img=org.opencv.highgui.Highgui.imread(imgLocation);
        List<Mat> imagesList=new ArrayList<Mat>();
        imagesList.add(img);
        int channelArray[]={0,1,2};
        MatOfInt channels=new MatOfInt(channelArray);
        Mat hist=new Mat();
        MatOfInt histSize=new MatOfInt(256);
        MatOfFloat ranges=new MatOfFloat(0.0f,255.0f);
        org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.calcHist(imagesList, channels,new Mat(), hist, histSize, ranges);
        return hist;
```

I got a error:

```
12-10 02:37:53.157: E/cv::error()(6203): OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (csz == 0 || csz == dims) in void cv::calcHist(cv::InputArrayOfArrays, const std::vector<int>&, cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, const std::vector<int>&, const std::vector<float>&, bool), file /home/reports/ci/slave_desktop/50-SDK/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/histogram.cpp, line 1427
```

Comment: By a quick search, you're not alone. http://answers.opencv.org/question/8967/java-api-histogram-calculation/ I haven't found any solutions yet. Maybe a bug in Opencv?

Answer (score 0):

I made it by that code:

```
    public void compare()
{
    String filenameLeft = null, filenameCurrent = null, filenameLeftHist = null, filenameCurrentHist = null;
    File fileLeft = null, fileCurrent = null, fileLeftHist = null, fileCurrentHist = null;
    File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES); // sciezka do sdcard
    fileLeft = new File(path, "left.png");fileCurrent = new File(path, "current.png"); fileLeftHist = new File(path, "leftHist.png"); fileCurrentHist  = new File(path, "currentHist.png");
    filenameLeft = fileLeft.toString(); filenameCurrent = fileCurrent.toString(); filenameLeftHist = fileLeftHist.toString(); filenameCurrentHist = fileCurrentHist.toString();

    Mat H1 = histogram(filenameLeft,filenameLeftHist);
    Mat H2 = histogram(filenameCurrent,filenameCurrentHist);
    double text = Imgproc.compareHist(H1, H2, Imgproc.CV_COMP_BHATTACHARYYA);
    if(text<0.2)Log.d(TAG,"Skrecam W LEWO, bo: "+text);
    else Log.d(TAG, "Nie skrecam w LEWO, bo: "+text);
}
public Mat histogram(String filenameIn,String filenameOut) // zwraca histogram obrazu
{
    Mat img = Highgui.imread(filenameIn);
    Mat src = new Mat(img.height(), img.width(), CvType.CV_8UC2);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(img, src, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
    Vector<Mat> bgr_planes = new Vector<Mat>();                                                                                                                                                                                 
    Core.split(src, bgr_planes);
    MatOfInt histSize = new MatOfInt(256);
    final MatOfFloat histRange = new MatOfFloat(0f, 256f);
    boolean accumulate = false;
    Mat b_hist = new  Mat();
    Imgproc.calcHist(bgr_planes, new MatOfInt(0),new Mat(), b_hist, histSize, histRange, accumulate);
    Highgui.imwrite(filenameOut, b_hist);
    return b_hist;
}
```

I using compare() in onCameraFrame() method. It is working good but i have question.

There is any option to make it more accurate ? It is much dependant on light, sometimes same layout mouth isnt working well. I using here comparing 2 histograms.

Comment: The second part of this answer is actually a question, you should not use an answer post for that. You should instead either edit your original question or post a new (different) question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify histsize for each channel.

So instead of

```
MatOfInt histSize=new MatOfInt(256);
```

try

```
MatOfInt histSize=new MatOfInt(256,256,256);
```

The same is true of ranges. Specify lower and upper bound for each channel also.